# mathjs number-only with typescript?

Tags: typescript, mathjs

I'm trying to use mathjs in a typescript project. I'd like to use the "number-only" part (avoiding BigNumbers and Fractions).
I've done `yarn add mathjs` and `yarn add @types/mathjs`.

In my code, I tried to import it like this:

```
import * as math from 'mathjs/number'
```

but I get a typescript error: `Could not find a declaration file for module 'mathjs/number'`

I can do `import * as math from 'mathjs'` but then I get `BigNumber`s popping up all over when I use it.
Anyone know how to use it like this?

Comment: It doesn't look like the type definition support this. You could make one using `declare module "mathjs/number" {  }` but I don't know what that should export.